# Is age of mythology tag needed?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup

In the question asked [here](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/225/was-poseidon-actually-jealous-of-zeus) the user decided to create a tag age of mythology. This tag refers to the popular game that includes mythology. Should we maintain this tag? Keep in mind that doing so will also spawn tags like God of war game, Darksiders game and other games that deal with mythology.

Comment: related http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/92/should-we-allow-tags-for-external-media